# How can i customize Render content elements

Tags: css, typo3, render, customization

With the TS variant, the article is displayed completely with media. How can I use an own template?
Or is there a way to transfer Media to Fluid template?

I use following code for News->[content element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7BkP.png)

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.contentElements}">
   <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering">
</f:if>
```

In TS:

```
lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering = RECORDS
lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering {
  
         tables = tt_content
         source.current = 1
         dontCheckPid = 1
```

How can i customize Render content elements in a own template?

However, this documentation describes a fluid template
with a debug issue I get no [media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF19S.png) for the content
https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/main/en-us/Tutorials/Templates/RenderContentElements/Index.html

Answer (score 1):

You could change the templates of fluid_styled_content and add a condition based on the pid of the record which would be the one of the sysfolder where the news is saved. that would be the easiest solution I guess.

Answer (score 1):

In the [original news extension detail template](https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/main/Resources/Private/Templates/News/Detail.html#L89) media is rendered like this:

```
<n:renderMedia news="{newsItem}" imgClass="img-responsive" videoClass="video-wrapper" audioClass="audio-wrapper">
    <f:if condition="{newsItem.teaser}">
        <!-- teaser -->
        <div class="teaser-text" itemprop="description">
            <f:format.html>{newsItem.teaser}</f:format.html>
        </div>
    </f:if>

    <f:if condition="{newsItem.contentElements}">
        <!-- content elements -->
        <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering">{newsItem.contentElementIdList}</f:cObject>
    </f:if>

    <f:render partial="Detail/MediaContainer" arguments="{media: newsItem.mediaNonPreviews, settings:settings}" />

    <!-- main text -->
    <div class="news-text-wrap" itemprop="articleBody">
        <f:format.html>{newsItem.bodytext}</f:format.html>
    </div>
</n:renderMedia>
```

Maybe this can solve your problem. But you will have to make the ViewHelper available by adding this first line to your custom template:

```
{namespace n=GeorgRinger\News\ViewHelpers}
```